# $Ric(\nabla f ,\nabla h)$ in local coordinates, for $f,g \in C^{3}(M)$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors

Let $(M,g)$ a Riemannian manifold. I'm having difficulties for find the expression for $Ric(\nabla f ,\nabla h)$, where $f,g \in C^{3}(M)$.

My notes says that $Ric(\nabla f ,\nabla h)=g^{ij}g^{kl}\nabla_{k}\nabla_{i}f\nabla_{l}\nabla_{j} h$. in a smooth coordinate system $(x^{i})$.

In my manipulation

- $Ric(\nabla f ,\nabla h)=Ric(g^{ij}\nabla_{i}f\partial_{j},g^{kl}\nabla_{l}h\partial_{k})=g^{ij}g^{kl}\nabla_{i}f\nabla_{l}hRic(\partial_{j},\partial_{k})=g^{ij}g^{kl}\nabla_{i}f\nabla_{l}hR_{jk}$ (*)

The affirmation is wrong? I don't know as continue (*)

Comment: Use the Riemann tensor $R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_X\nabla_YZ-\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$, and then the definition of Ricci.